# prove that the polynomial $(y-1/2)^2 -1/8$ minimizes its variation away from $0$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials

> Let $P(y)$ be a monic quadratic polynomial. Define the variation of P away from $0$ on $[0,1]$ to be $\max_{y\in [0,1]} |P(y)|$. Prove that $P(y) = (y-1/2)^2 -1/8$ has the minimum variation away from $0$ on $[0,1]$ of all monic quadratic polynomials.

Intuitively, this makes sense because the vertex should be at the midpoint of $0$ and $1$ and the polynomial should be "evenly spaced." Formally, I tried proving this result by assuming various cases. For instance, suppose the vertex is at $1/2 + d$ instead of 1/2, where we assume WLOG that $d>0$, suppose $f(y) = (y-(1/2+d))^2 + C$ for some constant $C$. I was only able to deduce relatively simple facts like $C \leq -1/8$, and I'm not sure how to get a contradiction. Assuming we have $|f(0)|,|f(1)|\leq \frac{1}8$, we obtain the inequalities $-\frac{3}8 - d - d^2 \leq C\leq -\frac{1}8 - d - d^2$ and $-\frac{3}8 + d - d^2\leq C \leq -\frac{1}8 + d - d^2$, which even when combined don't seem that useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P(y) = (y-1/2)^2 -1/8$ satisfies $\max_{y\in [0,1]} |P(y)| = 1/8$, also $P(0) = 1/8$, $P(1/2) = -1/8$, and $P(1) = 1/8$.

Now assume that $Q$ is a monic quadratic polynomial with $\max_{y\in [0,1]} |Q(y)| < 1/8$. Then $f(y) = Q(y) - P(y)$ is a *linear* polynomial with
$$
 f(0) = Q(0) - 1/8  < 0 \\
 f(1/2) = Q(1/2) + 1/8 > 0 \\
 f(1) = Q(1) - 1/8 > 0
$$
and that is not possible for a linear function $f$.

*Remark:* This is a special case of the [Minimal ∞-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials#Minimal_%E2%88%9E-norm) property of Chebyshev polynomials.